Why does `open_dataset` in R Arrow consume all RAM and crash my system, but selective queries work fine?
I am unable to run the following query:
df <- open_dataset("datos_2023.parquet")
When I attempt it, my system's RAM quickly gets consumed, causing severe slowdowns. I often need to force close R, and sometimes the system crashes with a Windows blue screen and restarts.
However, when I run this operation, it works without any issues and completes in just a few seconds:
open_dataset("datos_2023.parquet") %>%  select(value) |> collect() |> sum()
Additionally, I have an older laptop where the same code runs without problems. What could be causing this issue?
Im using arrow 17.0.0.1

You are working with an external database manager and your dataset is too large to fit into contiguous RAM (a requirement imposed by R for its objects.) So the first call fails. Database managers do not need to fit their operations into contiguous RAM so the second task succeeds.

@IRTFM , arrow::open_dataset() is supposed to return a lazy Dataset object, not something frame-like. I see no reason why the first call should trigger materialization.
